# Hyperlink does not change along with cell when filtered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I’m having a problem with hyperlink when using filters. So let’s say I have these table rows:

A

B

C

I have a hyperlink to cell C using the usual hyperlink option. But if I change the filter from “A to Z” to “Z to A” so it becomes:

C

B

A

then my link still points to the old cell C, which is now A. How can I make a link so that it will follow the C, not the cell it’s in? Thank you!

Comment: Per [@Mgonnet's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1815047/) the hyperlink must then follow the cell's contents rather than the cell's address.  You could add a unique ID column into your data then when you sort it you can use that ID as the lookup rather than the actual cells contents which may change.

Answer (score 1):

Sort procedure behaves like Copy. See below:
Before Sort
[image: Before sort]
After Sort
[image: After Sort]

Sorry for misunderstanding. As I told you already sort behaves like copy, not move. So for this other case you should use different formulas e.g.:
Before sort:
[image: Before sort 2]
After sort:
[image: After sort 2]

Comment: Sorry if my question seems a little bit vague since I can’t access Internet from my work’s PC for better visualization. But I don’t mean to sort the link but the destination. So in your example, if I sort G column from “Highest to Lowest” then the “A” link will point to 3 in G1. I’m looking for a way for it to track the destination content so no matter how I sort G column then “A” will always point to 1. I hope this does a better explanation for my question.

Comment: You can write it as `=HYPERLINK("#I"&MATCH(3,A:A,0),"A")` then you don't need to offset for row 6 (`6+MATCH(...`)